# How to end a resolved support ticket email?

Tags: phrase-requests, politeness

What is the best way to word an email meant to close a "help desk ticket" submitted via e-mail?

For instance, `Bob` sends an email to `Support Team` with a problem. After the `Support Team` solves the issue for `Bob`, and `Bob` acknowledges that the problem is fixed, what is the best way to say "Your problem is fixed, let us know if you experience any other problems"?

Not only would the purpose of this be to let the person know we're here, but to inform anyone else in the email group that the issue has been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just my opinion, but I like to conclude my support emails with, "Please don't hesitate to let us know if you have any further difficulties."

Answer (score 0):

Our support tickets usually close with the following stock line:

> We believe your Ticket has been resolved and have changed the status to “Closed.” If you feel it has not been completed, please notify the Service Center.

It's a fairly formal, wordy way of saying what you want to say, but is complete in nature and de-binds the responsibility of keeping the status updated from you to the user (if the problem is not resolved to their satisfaction).

The “your” and “you” is a bit questionable if multiple people can own the ticket. But it should be acceptable as a general "your" to all those who hold it.